# Is it good practice/advisable to sum up passages from a reference into a few sentences in my own paper?

Tags: journals, citations

Of course, I would retain the for me important points, but omit the details.

To the question in the title, I would like to add: If it is, how would it be best to point to that paper?
Should I reference this as a "regular" citation or is it better to include some explanation, like "From [5] it is clear that ..."?

Comment: Could expand more on the kind of explanation you want to include? I would not call "From [5] it is clear that ..." an explanation.

Comment: Also, "[5]" is not a noun.

Comment: @JeffE: You'll think I'm being sarcastic, but...I think it is of some philosophical interest whether your previous comment is in fact true.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I agree, although I'd say rather that it's of linguistic interest.  Maybe "[5]" is a pronoun?  Whether or not the quoted is phrase is grammatical, though, there's the separate question of whether it's good academic writing.

Comment: Whether it's good, grammatical, or otherwise, it is very common.

Comment: I would agree with @MarkMeckes that "[5]" could be considered a pronoun, since it substitutes the reference to the source in question (title, author(s), publisher, year, page, etc.). As of its use in academic writing, I've used it and I've seen many others who did, but I certainly can't claim that I'm an expert on those matters. However, I think it makes sense, because it keeps the notation short, concise and consistent; the title of the source is often very long and the author(s) may have other works that are cited in the paper, so that may not always be unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know people who restate whole *proofs* of mathematical theorems, either because the proof itself is interesting, or simply because the original presentation of the proof is poor in their opinion.

It is completely fine to summarize works of other people in your work, you just have to make it completely clear that it is not your work. But you can quote even whole paragraphs IMHO, without much problem (surely in math/natural science, I'm not sure how's it in philosophy and such).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem to sum up informations if they have been investigated already. You should reference this as a normal citation.

> "From [5] it is clear that ..."

It's better to write the title or the author's name (or research group) instead of reference number. If you take informations from a book or the like, you can use something like 'It is well known that... '